# How to use update-alternatives for a given user

Tags: debian

Is there any way to use update-alternative "user wide" ? I mean that it would be great to set preferences per user.

Does Debian provide some tools for that ?

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/811377/3654). In many situations this is not necessary (e.g. you can set environment variables instead), but it can be done if you want.

Answer (score 1):

sort of. `update-alternatives` can be used with the `--altdir` flag to specify some other directory than the usual `/etc/alternatives`.  This alternate directory can then be added to the user's `$PATH` environment variable in order to provide different executables per user.

this does not work for all things to which `update-alternatives` applies.  For example, attempting to set `x-cursor-theme` will not have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to chime in with a blatant promotion for the tool I just released that helps you configure per-user (or even per-shell !) alternatives:

- https://github.com/TekWizely/my-alternatives

You can initialize a shell-specific setup:

```
$ eval "$( my-alternatives init)"
```

Or you can initialize a long-lived user-level setup:

```
# run this once
$ eval "$( my-alternatives init ~/my-alts )"

# place this in your startup scripts
$ eval "$( my-alternatives shellenv ~/my-alts )"
```

Once configured, setting up a user-local alternative is as easy as:

```
# equivalent to 'update-alternatives --config <name>'
$ my-alternatives config <name>
```

**NOTE:** At the time of this posting, *my-alternatives* was just released.  As such, only `init` and `config` logic has been built.  Other features will come later.